# Context for creation of new components in the fragment or in static function?

Tags: android

Have situation when you need to create components dynamically in the fragment. I also have a static functions to create a specific components that is used many times in the application. 
Exist many opportunities to pass the context to the constructor.

**But what is the best practice if the static function or when extends from the fragment?**

I read a lot, but do not understand the entire picture. Thank you for your tips.

for example:

```
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        fragmentContext = (FragmentActivity) context;

or
getActivity()
or
getActivity().getApplicationContext()
or
getActivity().getBaseContext()
or
getContext()

or... or.. or....
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To create UI components, you should use Activity `context`. So that the Activity theme will be applied to the component. So you have 2 options in `Fragment`. One is saving the `context` at `onAttach()` and using that context to create components. Second one is using `getActivity()`. Both contexts are the host Activity context.

You should check whether the context is null, before using the context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer